# Mismatched braces in subscript and superscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

There is mismatch in the braces when used as subscript or superscript

```
\textit{ $ R(p_(a ),p_(b ) )=e^{(|(-\gamma {\lVert p_(a) - p_(b) \rVert})^2| )}$}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add an image of this, plus it is always a good idea here to provide a full minimal example not just a sniplet, then others do not have to guess what preamble you're using. Additionally, why the `\textit` what is that for here? Note the `{} ` aroung the `\lVert/rVert` has no purpose

Comment: You seem to have written parentheses `()` rather than braces `{}`. Since a parenthesis is a single token, only the left parenthesis is going to be subscripted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code:

- The `\textit` wrapper seems wholly unnecessary
- You seem to be under the impression that the `(` and `)` symbols perform grouping in TeX. That's not the case. I believe you should write `p_a` and `p_b` instead of `p_(a)` and `p_(b)`. If you must encase `a` and `b` in parentheses, you should write `p_{(a)}` and `p_{(b)}` to indicate to TeX that not just the opening parenthesis needs to be typeset in the subscript position.
- The outer pair of `|` symbols would appear to be redundant. The expression they encase is squared; hence, taking the absolute value is not needed, is it?
- The matching pair of curly braces around `\lVert ... \rVert` does not appear to serve a discernible purpose.
- To make the exponential term more readable, consider writing it as `\exp\{ ... \}` instead of as `e^{...}`. If you don't like the look of curly braces, consider using square brackets.

In short, this how I'd write the full expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \lVert and \rVert macros
\begin{document}
$ R(p_a,p_b) = \exp\{ (-\gamma \lVert p_a - p_b \rVert)^2 \}$
\end{document}
```